Prevent SQLCMD from truncating error messages
SQLCMD truncates my error long before I see the relevant part of the error. How can I make SQLCMD give me the full error message when the error message is very long?
-y 0 does not fix the problem.

What about -o to output to a file? Is there any reason you are using sqlcmd and not SSMS or another IDE?

are you sure the issue is what you think it is? The error messages from sql server aren't of unlimited length, so it might be already cut before it reaches sqlcmd. Or do you mean a flow of smaller errors is cut out?

@Charlieface Already tried -o and had no luck. I've also tried VS Code and that gives more length, but still not the full message.

@siggemannen It's certainly cut by SQLCMD. Visual Studio Code gives a longer error message.

do you have a script that can recreate the issue?

Why not compartmentalise? If you have lots of errors, break down the problem. the problem isn't sqlcmd it's your code; fix the code. sqlcmd isn't an IDE, so move to an environment you can debug your code in.

@siggemannen Just pass a really long string to RAISERROR. It cuts off around the 1000th character, even though RAISERROR can go far past that in other environments. My real example was an error in some very long dynamic SQL.

According to sqlcmd-go sources, screenwidth (-w) control the length of error message, unfortunately i couldnt recreate your issue on windows but you might wanna try -w 65000 or whatever

@siggemannen No luck with -w.
